# How to skip / ignore the empty fields of rows while appending to the python dataframe line by line?

Tags: python, pandas

Here am reading the input file

```
import time
import os
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pandas import ExcelWriter

ipfilepath = r"C:\Users\nmanthree\Desktop\m16\m16 nov\Satellite C2 PROD UK.txt"

data = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=['ID', 'Date/Time (UTC)', 'User', 'Description', 'Previous Value', 'New Value', 'Target User'])

The data inside the ip file is something like

ID    User     New Value    Previous Value    Target User 
1     Anil         10                        
2     Shyam        20             30            Jhon
3     Naren        30             40            Rose
```

We can see, there are empty fields in the column "Previous value" and "Target user".
Am reading the ip file line by line because the file size if huge and it is in txt format and appending each line to the dataframe.

```
with open(ipfilepath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as fp:
    for line in read_in_chunks(fp):
        if count == 0:
            count += 1
            continue
            data = data.append({'ID': fields[0],
                                'User': fields[1],
                                'Description': fields[2],
                                'New Value': fields[3],
                                'Previous Value': fields[4],
                                'Target User': fields[5]}
                               , ignore_index=True)
            count += 1
```

While appending, because there are empty fields in the columns "Previous value" and "Target user" for which am considering as fields[4] and fields[5] while appending, am getting the error as

```
'Previous Value': fields[3]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So, how can I skip / ignore the empty fields while appending the row data to dataframe. Please help me.

Comment: doesn't `pd.read_csv` work?

Comment: let pandas read the csv file for you

Answer (score 0):

You should read the file using pandas `read_csv`. This will read all rows, and will insert an `np.nan` where there are empty fields. No need to loop through the data yourself.

```
ipfilepath = r"C:\Users\nmanthree\Desktop\m16\m16 nov\Satellite C2 PROD UK.txt"
ip_df = pd.read_csv(ipfilepath)
```

```
print(ip_df.to_string())
ID    User     New Value    Previous Value    Target User 
1     Anil         10             NaN           NaN
2     Shyam        20             30            Jhon
3     Naren        30             40            Rose
```